# Ajax to call on same page within column

Tags: ajax, html, csv

Hey I am working with AJAX to display live CSV data on my webpage, Currently my AJAX script on button click. But I want it to show the data without refreshing or clicking the button in grid view but I am unable to figure it out.

Here's my attempt :-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#load_data').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "sample.csv",
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
        var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
        for (var count = 0; count < employee_data.length; count++) {
          var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
          table_data += '<tr>';
          for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
            if (count === 0) {
              table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
            } else {
              table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
            }
          }
          table_data += '</tr>';
        }
        table_data += '</table>';
        $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Click Load Data</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <h1 align="center">Please Click on Load Data</h1>
      <br />
      <div align="center">
        <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div id="employee_table">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy! All you need to do is call the data load function **on page ready** rather than adding it as a **`.click()`** callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "sample.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
      var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
      for (var count = 0; count < employee_data.length; count++) {
        var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
        table_data += '<tr>';
        for (var cell_count = 0; cell_count < cell_data.length; cell_count++) {
          if (count === 0) {
            table_data += '<th>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</th>';
          } else {
            table_data += '<td>' + cell_data[cell_count] + '</td>';
          }
        }
        table_data += '</tr>';
      }
      table_data += '</table>';
      $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Click Load Data</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <div id="employee_table">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I add it to a small box? (supposed I want to show a graph and this data) side by side in that case? @Derek Brown

Comment: You would just need to create another `div` on the side.  Take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I tried the same but it didn't work can you please help me embed it in my code?

Comment: I need some image on left and some data from AJAX in front of that @Derek Brown